# What is a valid string value for time(7)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Working on a ASP.NET MVC web application project that uses Entity Framework 6.0 and SQL Server 2014 database.

`START_TIME` column is defined as `time(7)`. When the View posts back a value like `08:00 am` the Controller sends back this error.

> "The value '08:00 am' is not valid for START_TIME."

Isn't the `hh:mm tt` format supported as described in the [Supported String Literal formats for time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) section?

Omitting `tt` in the format works. But I need to have that. I don't want to use military time if at all possible.

*EDIT* (adding model's properties screenshot):

[image]

Comment: What is the property type in your model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke screenshot added

Comment: post the time in 24-hour format:  `HH:mm`

Comment: @SamAxe do you know for sure it's a requirement to use time(7) and there is no workaround? I'm trying to avoid military time here.

Comment: @greatbear302 -- the data type TIME in TSQL, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),  _The time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock_

Comment: @DavidTansey did you get a chance to see the "Supported String Literal formats for time" section? `hh:mm tt`  format is supported. Then why is EF throwing that error? Question has nothing to do with time zones, and am and pm do work for 24 hour clock. I think you're reading "24-hour clock" as "24-hour format"

Comment: @greatbear302 -- your points are good ones.  I pasted the text verbatim which is the reason for the reference to TZ (however irrelevant).  I think what you might be seeing is that EF does not deal with the string literal conversion the same way as SQL Server does directly -- which would explain why the SQL Server docs reference a string literal format that is causing you problems in EF.  Sorry for any misdirection or confusion from previous comment.

Comment: @greatbear302 -- the message `The value '08:00 am' is not valid for START_TIME.` is a message from ASP.NET MVC validation of the model.  Can you try to rig a test of your controller that will attempt to use the string literal format you want to use (for updating EF / SQL), by hardcoding the string literal value (to temporarily bypass the ASP.NET MVC validation blocker)?

Comment: @DavidTansey you're right - it's an EF issue and not SQL Server issue. EF is treating `time(7)` as `TimeSpan`. I ended up formatting the `START_TIME` value via JavaScript before posting to controller.